# Thymeleaf - recuperar los datos desde el html al controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Teniendo el siguiente `controller`

```
@PostMapping("/duplicats")
public ModelAndView fusionaDuplicats(@RequestParam("action") String action,
                                     @ModelAttribute("duplicatsForm") DuplicatsForm duplicatsForm) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    .
    .
    return model;
}
```

Quisiera que el `thymeleaf` me retornara los datos de los 'inputs' y poder tratarlos desde el controlador. (Ahora me pinta los datos en los `inputs` correctamente)

He probado con el 

pero no me retorna el dato y ni si quiera me lo pinta.

Este es el `form`

```
<form th:action="@{/duplicats}" th:object="${duplicatsForm}" method="POST">
                <div class="row" th:each="duplicat : ${llistaDuplicats}">

 <!--                        <input class="form-control" th:text="#{duplicat.idDuplicat}" th:field="*{idDuplicat}">-->

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Dades bàsiques</h3>
                        <!--<div class="row" style="border-style: solid">-->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nom1">Nom</label>
                                    <input th:value="${duplicat.possibleDuplicat.nom}" type="text" class="form-control" id="nom1" readonly>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="cognoms1">Cognoms</label>
                                    <input th:value="${duplicat.possibleDuplicat.cognom1 + ' ' + duplicat.possibleDuplicat.cognom2}"type="text" class="form-control" id="cognoms1" readonly>
                                </div>
```

Esta es la clase Duplicat

```
public Duplicat {
   Integer idDuplicat;

   String nom;
   String cognoms;
   String tipusDocument;
   String document;

   String cn;
   String idGauss;

   Boolean dadesPossibleDuplicat;
   Boolean dadesCandidat;
   Boolean cnIdGaussPossibleDuplicat;
   Boolean cnIdGaussCandidat;

   List<String> perfils;
   . 
   .
   .

}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stackoverflow. El problema que veo es que quieres obtener un String (action) desde una petición POST. 

@PostMapping("/duplicats")
public ModelAndView fusionaDuplicats(@RequestParam("action") String action,
                                     @ModelAttribute("duplicatsForm") DuplicatsForm duplicatsForm) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView()


Deberías tener otro método, pero usando @GetMapping.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si sigues a día de hoy con ese problema, pero te ayudo con un ejemplo.

Para pasar el parámetro, primero debemos tener un contenedor, ya sea una caja de texto, por ejemplo, donde escribamos el valor de nuestra variable, a la cual le añadiremos la etiqueta `th:name:`

```
<input type="text" id="tiempo" th:name="tiempo" placeholder="Tiempo en minutos"></input>
```

Después, en el controlador, ponemos una variable por parámetro del método, de la siguiente manera:

```
public String funcionDelControlador(@RequestParam(value = "tiempo", defaultValue = "1") int tiempo) {
```

El **defaultValue** es opcional, pero viene bien por si se deja el campo vacío, en este caso es int, la variable será del tipo que nosotros declaremos, si vamos a usar números no tenemos por qué hacer transformaciones desde String, independientemente de que el input sea una caja de texto.

**Importante: *El objeto de donde se saca el valor, debe estar en el mismo formulario que llama al método post**